# What's the difference between 'modules' in YIi and 'packages' in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, yii

I've worked with Yii 1.1.x extensively and I'm in the process of learning Laravel 4.x.

In Yii I've used modules to separate out functionality, such as the main user-facing site (module/app) vs. an admin panel (module/admin). The closest equivalent I've found in Laravel is the package, but these seem to be more "stand-alone" in nature than a Yii module.

I'm wondering what the different use-cases would be for a Laravel package, and if the concept is a subset or superset of a Yii module. Are there things I can do with a package but not with a module, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii's modules are application specific, part of the [HMVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture. An often abused feature because it makes it easy to reuse code by calling other controllers, or because some people want to use it for simply organizing their code into different directories.

Packages can be described most precisely as external libraries. They should be abstract and usable by any other application.